# Setting LCD resolution with XRandR reduces the image to upper left corner, is it possible to scale it fullscreen?

Tags: linux, debian, resolution, xrandr

I run Debian Linux on Compaq Presario C500 laptop. Xorg detects my video adapter as "Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) 945GM" using `intel_drv.so` driver. `xrandr` claims to support 640x480 video mode:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 800, maximum 4096 x 4096
LVDS1 connected 1280x800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 331mm x 207mm
1280x800       60.0*+
1024x768       60.0  
800x600        60.3     56.2  
640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
TV1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

However, when I switch my screen to 640x480, the active area is reduced to upper left corner:

[image]

Is it possible to scale my low-resolution desktop to occupy the whole screen?